# How to automatically add parentheses around fractions?

Tags: superscripts, delimiters, fractions

Is there any way to make LaTeX automatically put parentheses around a `\frac` if it is followed by a superscript expression?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could redefine `\frac` to look ahead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\old@frac=\frac
\def\frac#1#2{%
 \@ifnextchar^
  {\left(\old@frac{#1}{#2}\right)}
  {\old@frac{#1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}^2$. 

 \[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}^2\]
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Genius!! I was about to comment that it can't be done, but thought it better to wait...  Not that I think this is a good idea to do, but good to know that it can be done.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Funny thing is, I was *also* about to comment that it can't be done.  I also agree that it isn't a good idea, but I didn't say that in my answer because I couldn't actually think of a concrete reason why.  It just seems wrong.

Comment: I think it is a personal preference thing. I don't like seeing `\frac12` even though it produces `1/2`, but perhaps others do.

Comment: Oh, I agree about that for sure, but the thing with parentheses seems more questionable. In other contexts I'd say it is enforcing a default choice you may not always want, but I really can't think of when one would want a fraction with a superscript but no parentheses; it's always ambiguous.